# JQuery UI Sortable strange placeholder behaviour

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following JSFiddle:

> https://jsfiddle.net/353fa42p/4/

Below is simply an excerpt from the JS file:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(".box-item-scroll-contents").sortable({
        appendTo: "body",
        connectWith: ".item-objects-area,.box-item-scroll-contents",
        handle: ".drag",
        items: ".box-item,.box-item-object"
    }).disableSelection();

    $(".item-objects-area").sortable({
        appendTo: "body",
        connectWith: ".box-item-scroll-contents,.item-objects-area",
        handle: ".drag-inner",
        items: ".box-item-object,.box-item"
    }).disableSelection();

    $(".open").on("click", function(){
        var objArea = $(this).closest(".box-item").find(".item-objects-area");
        if( objArea.is(":visible") ){
            objArea.hide();
        }
        else{
            objArea.show();
        }
    });
});
```

If you drag 'item 4' up the left-hand side of the list the placeholder does not appear. Now, if you reset the positions, then drag 'item 4' up the right-hand side of the list, the placeholder shows ok !
Now, if you then rest the positions again and open 'item 5' up, then drag 'item 4' up the list, the placeholder works ok no matter what side of the list it is dragged! Any ideas as to what is causing this erratic behaviour?

Note: there will be more than one 'box-item-scroll-area' block on the page, so the items in the 'box-item-scroll-area' and 'item-objects-area' will need to be interchangable between themselves and between those list in the other 'box-item-scroll-area' blocks on the page.

Comment: From your fiddle, I can understand that the white boxes are `.box-item`, and their container is `.box-item-scroll-contents`. What is `.box-item-object`, `.item-objects-area` etc?! I don't see them in ui?

Comment: They are elements that exist when you open up 'item 5'. These are hidden by default, simply becuase when toggling the visibility of these affects the behaviour of the sorting of items.

Comment: Did you really intend on sorting/transferring a parent box siblings as children? What I mean is I can drag one of outer sortable boxes and drop inside item 5. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is initializing sortable on a hidden container. This can be fixed by initializing the sortable on .item-objects-area after it is visible, then destroy the sortable when is hidden. Not ideal, but it works. Here is the adjustment to the 'open' function to illustrate:

```
$(".open").on("click", function(){
    var objArea = $(this).closest(".box-item").find(".item-objects-area");
    if( objArea.is(":visible") ){
        if (objArea.hasClass('ui-sortable')) {
            objArea.sortable("destroy");
        }
        objArea.hide();
    }
    else{
        objArea.show();
        if (!objArea.hasClass('ui-sortable')) {
            objArea.sortable({
                appendTo: "body",
                connectWith: ".box-item-scroll-contents,.item-objects-area",
                handle: ".drag-inner",
                items: ".box-item-object,.box-item"
            }).disableSelection();
        }
    }
});
```

You will also need to initialize the sortable on both the outer (.box-item-scroll-contents) and nested (.item-objects-area) containers - here is the adjusted JSFiddle to show the working example in full: https://jsfiddle.net/353fa42p/9/

Answer (score 3):

You usually want to refer to the topmost `class` or `id` that the sortable will `connectWith`.

Adjusting your sortable `connectWith` property to use `.box-item` resolves this erratic behavior.

Original:

```
$(".box-item-scroll-contents").sortable({
    appendTo: "body",
    connectWith: ".item-objects-area,.box-item-scroll-contents",
    handle: ".drag",
    items: ".box-item,.box-item-object"
}).disableSelection();
```

Working version (see jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/sz2hvme4/)

```
$(".box-item-scroll-contents").sortable({
    appendTo: "body",
    connectWith: ".box-item",
    handle: ".drag",
    items: ".box-item,.box-item-object"
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: This doesn't work very well as when dragging an item form the outer list to the inner list. Also, the reason for having the .box-item-scroll-contents class as the connectWith parameter is because ultimately there will be more than one on the page, i.e. in the JSFiddle example, more than one .box-item-scroll-area block on the page.

Comment: @JoePrivett, it answered your original question, which I see was now edited to reflect the change in requirements.

Comment: You'll need to do some class changing in order to get your 'open' links to occur on the inner ones that become outers, and vice versa (or really adjust your CSS to automatically handle this).  This simply is not a draggable/droppable question anymore.